# How to upload file with libcurl + POST?

Tags: c, file-upload, libcurl

I am trying to upload a file to a webserver using libcurl (in C). The server requires that I use POST, not PUT (which is what CURLOPT_UPLOAD would use). I am able to successfully upload the file with status 200 but when I download the file from server it is empty. There is no issue with server as I have verified with POSTMAN it accepts POST for file and sends the file along with content when downloaded.

```
int HttpUploadFile(const char *url, const char *filePath, Buffer 
*response){
  int status;
   CURL *handle;
   FILE *fp;
   struct stat file_info;

   int exist = stat(filePath, &file_info);
   if(exist != 0) {
     ERROR("stat() failed: %s", strerror(errno));
     return -1;
   }

  fp = fopen(filePath, "rb");
   if (fp == NULL) {
      ERROR("fopen() failed for file : %s %s", filePath, 
strerror(errno));
      return -1;
   }

   status = HttpInitHandle(url, &handle);
   if (status != 0) {
      fclose(fp);
      return -1;
   }

   curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, url);
   curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_READDATA, fp);
   curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
   curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE,
                    file_info.st_size);
   curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, HttpReceiveCb);
   curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)response);
   status = HttpSendRequest(handle);
   fclose(fp);
   return status;
}
```

In HttpSendRequest I am adding headers and sending the request.

Is there something wrong with POST options set?

Comment: Have you tried using the `curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);` option?

Comment: Just found code about https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fileupload.html